# Chrome autofill options really long

Tags: html, google-chrome, autocomplete

We have a site with a pretty simple site search form at the top like this:

```
<div class="siteSearch">
    <form id="search_form" method="GET" action="/search" novalidate>
        <input id="search_text"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Sitewide Search"
                aria-label="Enter a search term for the site search. Press enter to search"
                name="s" />
        <input type="submit" class="site-search-input" value="" />
    </form>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Our problem is that if, using chrome, I paste a paragraph of lorem ipsum text into the site search form and then go back to the form later and start typing the word, "lorem", I get an autocomplete so long that it sometimes stretches off of both of my monitors. Other times, it will show up above the form input and stretch way off to the right. I've seen cases where the autocomplete options were so large that it was impeding my ability to use the site navigation or read the content of the site. I need to figure out how to truncate the autofill options. I want to constrain the width. Any ideas? My hope is that we can fix the autocomplete and that I don't have to resort to `autocomplete="off"`.

I was using Chrome 68 when I was reproducing this.

Thanks

Comment: hmm I couldn't find anything easy online, but if you are really set on having the feature you could implement your own autocomplete described here: [Create an Autocomplete Form](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp) But the ArrayList could be stored and accessed from a db so when the user types a new search term it would be saved to the array list in the db, then for each list item you could cut down the size if it's too long before displaying it as an autocomplete.